# Creating a CFG from an English text in spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I've been using the [pyStatParser](https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser) library to generate a context free grammar from a text, like this:

```
import stat_parser
p = stat_parser.Parser()
grammar = set()
for sentence in sent_tokenize("sometext"):
    grammar.update(set(p.parse(sentence).productions()))
print(grammar)
```

**Input**:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

**Output**

```
[NP+S -> NP VP, NP -> DT NN, DT -> 'the', NN -> 'quick', VP -> VB NP, VB -> 'brown', NP -> NP PP, NP -> JJ NN, JJ -> 'fox', NN -> 'jumps', PP -> IN NP, IN -> 'over', NP -> DT JJ NN, DT -> 'the', JJ -> 'lazy', NN -> 'dog']
```

From this grammar, it is then easy to derive random sentences.
**However**, this is very time-intensive, so I've looked at other libraries, and found [Spacy](https://spacy.io). I can't find a way to create a CFG like I used to do with the previous library though.

**Question**: Can I create CFGs in spacy ? If not, how can I use this library to analyze a text's grammar and then derive a new sentence from this grammar ?

Answer (score 1):

Spacy parses and creates dependency relationships. The trees that result from a dependency grammar can have a one-to-one mapping to trees that result from a context-free grammar. However, Spacy is not applying an explicit grammar in order to parse. Rather it is using a neural network to decide how to place the dependency relationships on a case by case basis, so if you wanted to derive a context-free grammar from a large set of the resulting parse trees, you might find that the result is under-constrained. The neural networks which underlie the parser and the tokeniser have been trained on corpora, each of which has been hand-annotated according to a certain grammar, so it might make sense to go back to the source and get the grammar(s) used to parse the corpora.